# Can't deploy serverless flask app using serverless-python-requirements STDERR:

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

following this https://www.serverless.com/blog/flask-python-rest-api-serverless-lambda-dynamodb

for build some flask application on AWS Lambda

I already activate venv with python3.8

```
virtualenv venv --python=python3
source venv/bin/activate
```

I'm fine with local but I can't deploy app to AWS Lambda here is my error

```
Error --------------------------------------------------
 
  Error: STDOUT: Collecting boto3
    Using cached boto3-1.17.74.tar.gz (98 kB)
  Collecting flask
    Using cached Flask-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (93 kB)
  Collecting keras
    Using cached Keras-2.4.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Collecting numpy
    Using cached numpy-1.20.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.4 MB)
  Collecting opencv-python
    Using cached opencv_python-4.5.2.52-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (51.0 MB)
  Collecting tensorflow
```

Here is my serverless.yml

```
service: flask-app

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
  - serverless-wsgi
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8
  stage: dev
  region: ap-southeast-1
  versionFunctions: false
  profile: serverless-agent
  memorySize: 128
  timeout: 30
  logRetentionInDays: 14
  logs:
    restApi: true
  environment:
    NODE_ENV: ${self:provider.stage}
    AWS_PROFILE: ${self:provider.profile}

  vpc:
    securityGroupIds:
      - sg-xxxx
    subnetIds:
      - subnet-xxxx
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      Resource:
        - "*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "s3:PutObject"
        - "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        - "s3:GetObject"
        - "s3:ListBucket"
        - "s3:DeleteObject"
      Resource:
        - "*"
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Resource:
        - Fn::Join:
            - ":"
            - - arn:aws:lambda
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - Ref: AWS::AccountId
              - function:${self:service}-${self:provider.stage}-*

    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "sqs:SendMessage"
      Resource:
        - "*"
        
functions:
  app:
    handler: wsgi.handler
    events:
      - http: ANY /
      - http: 'ANY {proxy+}'
  
package:
  individually: true
  exclude:
    - ./node_modules/**
    - ./venv/**

custom:
  webpack:
    packager: "npm"
    keepOutputDirectory: true
    includeModules:
      forceExclude:
        - aws-sdk
  warmup:
    default: true
    memorySize: 128
    timeout: 60
    prewarm: true
    schedule: rate(1 minute)
    concurrency: 1
  wsgi:
    app: app.app
    packRequirements: false
  pythonRequirements:
    dockerizePip: non-linux
```

and my dependencies in requirements.txt

```
flask
numpy
tensorflow
keras
opencv-python
boto3
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

I already knew it because I test on AWS console and it have no http header.
It's when I use postman.